# MySQL how to optimize %LIKE% query?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, full-text-search, sql-like

Trying to optimize MySQL query. The reason of needed optimization is table growth.
For now it has approx 300K rows and in future it will be much more.

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `activity_log` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `event_id` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `activity_by` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '''0'' - by client himself; ''-1'' - by admin; other - ap_user.id;',
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  `ip` char(46) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `activity_log`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `client_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD KEY `event_id` (`event_id`),
  ADD KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  ADD KEY `ip` (`ip`);
ALTER TABLE `activity_log` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`);

ALTER TABLE `activity_log`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2435463;
COMMIT;
```

Query need to optimize:

```
SELECT a.id,a.activity_by,a.user_id,a.date_created,
            DATE_FORMAT(a.date_created,'%e %b, %Y') as date,
            DATE_FORMAT(a.date_created,'%H:%i') as time ,
            a.text,a.notes,e.color,e.link_icon,  u.id as user_id, u.login, r.role 
                  FROM `activity_log` a
                        LEFT JOIN `ap_user` u ON a.activity_by = u.id
                        LEFT JOIN `ap_role` r ON u.role_id = r.id,
                  `activity_log_events` e
                  WHERE 1
                  AND a.event_id=e.id
                  AND a.text LIKE '%test tester%'
         ORDER BY `date_created` DESC, `id` DESC
```

What I already tried is to replace %LIKE% query with FULLTEXT

```
SELECT a.id,a.activity_by,a.user_id,a.date_created,
        DATE_FORMAT(a.date_created,'%e %b, %Y') as date,
        DATE_FORMAT(a.date_created,'%H:%i') as time ,
        a.text,a.notes,e.color,e.link_icon,  u.id as user_id, u.login, r.role 
              FROM `activity_log` a
                    LEFT JOIN `ap_user` u ON a.activity_by = u.id
                    LEFT JOIN `ap_role` r ON u.role_id = r.id,
              `activity_log_events` e
              WHERE 1
              AND a.event_id=e.id
    AND MATCH (a.text) AGAINST ('test tester*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `date_created` DESC, `id` DESC
```

At finish this query will has its `LIMIT 15` approx for DataProvider and pagination if this info is important.

So I added `FULLTEXT index` and placed fake data into this table and it has ~1 million rows.

The one of the strange things is that `like` query gives 1300 results for 1 million rows table and `MATCH` query gives 200_000 for the same table.

First thought this is because of table contains equal rows as I duplicated them for test. Is that possible? `FULLTEXT` search is very slow because of that and `like` search gives unfair results - 1k instead of 200k.
This is specific table that anyway will contain a lot of similar words like names and standard phrases like "has added" or "has removed".

How to optimize this `%like%` query? Is it possible without `FULLTEXT`? If not - what exactly am I doing wrong with `FULLTEXT` query?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This might help: [https://ohdoylerules.com/tricks/handle-spaces-and-no-spaces-in-mysql-where-like-clauses/](https://ohdoylerules.com/tricks/handle-spaces-and-no-spaces-in-mysql-where-like-clauses/)

Comment: @RobMoll thanks, but that's not an issue, I'm searching text by one and only field in current table, so there is no need in CONCAT.

Comment: `AGAINST ('test tester*')` looks for test **or** tester* **anywhere** in that string, while `like '%test tester%'` looks for exactly these letters directly behind each other (e.g. the first "word" can just *end* with "test") and in that order. As to how to optimize your query: try `AGAINST ('+test +tester*' in boolean mode)` to at least find both, maybe that solves it. But in general, a fulltext index is a tool to find *rare* words. If 200k out of 1kk rows match, you are either using extremely unlucky or very atypical test words/test database content, or you may need to redesign your model.

Comment: There are several things wrong with Doyle's blog; anyway I don't see much relevance.

Comment: Please provide some strings that should match and some that should not.  `MATCH...AGAINST("test")` will [I think] match "test tester" or even just "tester".  If you specifically want the word "test" with no suffix, Fulltext is overkill since it matches "tests", "testing", etc.

Comment: And some other things you may or may not want:  "retest", "test-like", "testosterone".

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY` is ambiguous; I'm surprised it did not give you a syntax error.  There are two tables with `id`.

Is there a reason for using Aria instead of InnoDB?

Consider changing to

```
('+test +tester*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Consider also

```
('+"test tester*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

And, to double check with `LIKE`:

```
MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)
AND text LIKE "..."
```

This last suggestion handles some cases where FULLTEXT will efficiently find the 'words', then LIKE makes sure they are together.  For example to avoid matching "test or tester" (because of the intervening word).  Or "James Smith and Bob Doyle".